# pass 3 rows while applying a function to a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a table that looks like this:

```
sumOfSquares      mean     n     std     val
12                323      2             xd
543               42       5             dwjo
```

I want to use the following formula, pass df.sumOfSquares and df.mean from each row to calculate df.std for each row.

```
def calculateSD(sumOfSquares, mean, n):
    nominator = sumOfSquares - (mean*mean)
    denominator = n-1
    return nominator/denominator
```

How can I apply the function in such a way that all 3 required cols get passed and the returned value is added to the df.std col?

Comment: `df['std'] = calculateSD(df['sumOfSquares'], df['mean'], df['n'])`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if passing in the entire row is an option, but you could use `apply` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

def calculateSD(row):
  sumOfSquares = row['sumOfSquares']
  mean = row['mean']
  n = row['n']
  nominator = sumOfSquares - (mean*mean)
  denominator = n-1
  return nominator/denominator

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    "sumOfSquares": [12, 543],
    "mean": [323, 42],
    "n": [2, 5],
    "val": ["xd", "dwjo"]
  }
)

df['sd'] = df.apply(calculateSD, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Getting the following result:

```
   sumOfSquares  mean  n   val         sd
0            12   323  2    xd -104317.00
1           543    42  5  dwjo    -305.25
```

Comment: Why use `apply` when you can perform a vector operation?

Comment: OP asked about apply as far as I understand. But you could do it either way. I don't think it matters that much in this case.

Comment: I don't think OP meant `apply` as the function, more English language apply ;) (otherwise why asking the question?)